# Como adicionar códigos nativos de 64 e 32 bits em um app Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, gradle

Estou tento problemas para publicar a versão de um app. A Play store está me notificando sobre a nova arquitetura de 32 e 64 bits:

> *"Esta versão não está em conformidade com o requisito de 64 bits do Google Play
>   Os seguintes APKs ou pacotes de apps estão disponíveis para dispositivos de 64 bits. No entanto, eles só têm códigos nativos de 32 bits: 22.
>   Inclua códigos nativos de 64 e 32 bits no seu app. Use o formato de publicação do Android App Bundle para garantir que cada arquitetura do dispositivo receba automaticamente só o código nativo necessário. Isso evitará o aumento do tamanho geral do seu app. [Saiba mais](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#building_with_android_studio_or_gradle)"*

Segui os passos da documentação, mas ainda assim não consegui adicionar suporte 64 bits no código do meu projeto. Também não encontrei muita coisa relacionada além da documentação oficial.

Aparentemente eles pedem para adicionar esta linha no gradew para quem usa Android Studio:

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

Porém as pastas com suporte a bibliotecas 64 bits ainda não são geradas pelo apk.

Comment: Essa configuração e as que estão sendo apresentadas nas respostas, só dará certo se você estiver utilizando o `ANDROID_NDK` para gerar algo com código nativo `C/C++`. -- Se esse não é seu caso, então provavelmente você esta utilizando algum Framework de terceiro que não esta com suporte a 64bits.

Comment: Se você estiver fazendo builds com o `ANDROID_NDK`, então talvez valha a pena você adicionar na sua pergunta as configurações utilizadas no `CMake` ou `ndk-build`, para a comunidade entender melhor seu problema. -- Para adicionar mais informações click em [edit] em baixo de sua pergunta.

Answer (score -2):

Precisa adicionar em

```
 ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86","arm64-v8a","x86_64"
        }
```

```
 abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86","arm64-v8a","x86_64"
        }
```

```
 def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a":3,"x86_64":4 ]
```

Isso resolveu aqui, espero que te ajude tb

Comment: Então, onde devo por esse abi{} e def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a":3,"x86_64":4 ]? eu tentei aqui, mas dá erro ao sincronizar.

Comment: Estou usando Android Studio. Já consegui gerar um apk sem as libs, mas ainda n consegui gerar com as libs de 64. Será que existe alguma linha de comando que impeça essa geração? ou será que essa lib não possui suporte para 64? Não sei a qual biblioteca se refere "libImageProc.so" para procurar na documentação dela.

Comment: Por onde? Capaz que eu vou ter que abandonar meu app por causa disso, a Google ta de brincadeira...

Answer (score -2):

[image: Adicione Este comando no compiler]

```
import com.android.build.OutputFile

android {

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.package"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    multiDexEnabled = true
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
    }
}
splits {
    density {
        enable true
        reset()
        include "mdpi", "hdpi"
    }
    abi {
        reset()
        // enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
    }
}
ext.abiCodes = ['armeabi-v7a': 1, 'x86': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3, 'x86_64': 4]
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def versionCodes = ['armeabi-v7a': 1, 'x86': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3, 'x86_64': 4]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}
```